# HTML emails no spacing

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

What I have currently: 
http://i.gyazo.com/b3111f32a78e86504d8a555f0adad3de.png

What I want to make:
http://i.gyazo.com/2d6c75649401e1b5dc9825d6e427791f.png

Ignore the borders/stroke just for me to see clearly what Im looking at.

What I want to do is to make it so there is no space whatsoever between each table cell row and column.
How Would I go about doing this?
Current code:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyJu43v.png">
        </td>
        <td >
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vSAgEXE.png">
        </td>
        <td >
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ih5jtiC.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9B9Wcit.png">
        </td>
        <td>
        The new Insight Snapshot newsletter from Opinion Matters is packed full of research<br />
        and communication ideas to inform your next project. Featuring tips for data<br />
        storytelling, ways to interact with your target audience through online quizzes and<br />
        case study examples of recent international survey campaigns.<br />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lNwkYpL.png">
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="i.imgur.com/eCje9hy.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        If you would like to speak to a member of the team regarding any of the features in the <br/>newsletter please call 0207 251 9960 or email newsletter@opinionmatters.com<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="i.imgur.com/mC6Pytj.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide your css code.

Comment: I didn't use css code.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are too big and are causing the cells to expand. This is how I altered your html:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr style="line-height:10px;">
    <td colspan="2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyJu43v.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vSAgEXE.png">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ih5jtiC.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9B9Wcit.png">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">The new Insight Snapshot newsletter from Opinion Matters is packed full of research
      <br />and communication ideas to inform your next project. Featuring tips for data
      <br />storytelling, ways to interact with your target audience through online quizzes and
      <br />case study examples of recent international survey campaigns.</td>
    <td rowspan="4" align="right">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3yl.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eCje9hy.png" width="460px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">If you would like to speak to a member of the team regarding any of the features in the
      <br />newsletter please call 0207 251 9960 or email newsletter@opinionmatters.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhiKK.png" width="481px">
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDXGv.png" width="57px" height="96px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I changed two of your images and made into three images. They are [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3yl.png), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhiKK.png) and [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDXGv.png).

Comment: Thanks forgot to mention I already fixed the issue I had to create 2 separate tables.